# Enum class operator override

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum class defined like so in myClass.h:

```
enum class SpeedMode {
  SPEED_SLOW = 0,
  SPEED_NORMAL = 1,
  SPEED_FAST = 2
};
```

In another file I'd like to use my enum as an int:

```
void myOtherClass::myFunc(const SpeedMode& speed_mode) {
  int speed_as_int = speed_mode;
.
.
.
}
```

In the same file I defined my enum (myClass.h) I try to define an operator override:

```
int operator= (const SpeedMode& mode) {
   return static_cast<int>(mode); //The real logic is more complex and will use a switch statement
}
```

But I get this error:  `error: 'int operator=(const SpeedMode&)' must be a nonstatic member function`.

If I try to wrap it in something like `struct SpeedModeUtils { }` which allows that file to compile but then myOtherClass gives me this error where I try to make use of the override:
`error: cannot convert 'const SpeedMode' to 'int' in initialization`

I'm aware I could use the old non-class enum, but this is a large project and I much prefer the type safety of an enum class. I'm also aware I can use static_cast but I'd prefer to avoid that for likely obvious reasons.

If this fails I'll simply use a manual conversion function, but figured this would be a 'nicer' way of handling this.

Comment: What is `SpeedMode`? you enum is called `Speed` you have shown no structure called `SpeedMode`

Comment: Additonally I have another. 1) Why are you using `enum class` and not just `enum`? If you use the later you enum will be just an integer representation and you can say `int convertSpeedToInt(Speed mode) {return mode;}`

Comment: I'm hoping to have type safety on the enum class, though yes, a simple helper function containing a switch statement is what I think I'm settling on.

Comment: Just to be sure, what you mean with type safety is that you can avoid comparing against other enums and ints right?

Comment: Yes, that mostly describes it. Also to avoid name collision by enforcing usage with SpeedMode::SPEED_SLOW vs just using SPEED_SLOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need access to the underlying data type of the enum class, meaning the int.
The way to do this is to use `std::underlying_type<T>` to access the integer value.
The way you do this is:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

auto speed_mode_as_int = static_cast<std::_underlying_type<SpeedMode>::type>(speed_mode);
```

I made a minimum working example here which should get you started

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

enum class SpeedMode {
    SPEED_SLOW = 0,
    SPEED_NORMAL = 1,
    SPEED_FAST = 2
    
};

bool is_fast(const SpeedMode& speed_mode)
{
    auto speed_mode_as_int =
        static_cast<std::underlying_type<SpeedMode>::type>(speed_mode);

    switch(speed_mode_as_int)
    {
    case 2:
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
    

int main(void) {

    auto mode = SpeedMode::SPEED_SLOW;

    assert(false == is_fast(mode));
    mode = SpeedMode::SPEED_NORMAL;
    assert(false == is_fast(mode));
    mode = SpeedMode::SPEED_FAST;
    assert(true == is_fast(mode));
        
    return 0; 
}
```

I compiled it with the following compile string: `clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp`.

Comment: Thank you, this is essentially what I ended up doing yesterday. Not quite as clean as I was hoping, but it is a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

As a compiler said you, you can't define such an assignment operator. It said `int operator=(const SpeedMode&)' must be a nonstatic member function`, enums just do not have members in C++.

Comment: Yes, I understood that part, which is why I tried to wrap it in the Util struct, but how do I make it globally available? (Or at least anywhere myClass.h is included)

Comment: Could you please be more clear? I understood that you didn't successfully implement Util struct yet, so what do you want to make "globally available"?

Comment: As simply and clearly as I can ask: How do I import the operator= override so that it will be used in myOtherClass?

Comment: @Fozefy You don't. That's simply not possible.